# Why is UIFont sizeWithFont including blank space in its calculation?

Tags: ios, uilabel, uifont

I am setting a UILabels frame based on what is returned by UIFont sizeWithFont but for whatever reason when i use a custom font, the values that are returned include some padding as seen below.

When i use **boldSystemFontOfSize** the text is vertically aligned in the middle (*which is what i want*), but when i use **fontWithName** i end up with padding under the text.  Any reason why **sizeWithFont** is adding in the padding?

[image]

Heres my code...

```
CGRect frameLabel = label.frame;
CGSize sizeLabel = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font];
frameLabel.size.width = sizeLabel.width;
frameLabel.size.height = sizeLabel.height;
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

** Edit **

I can calculate the top and bottom padding using this code and adjust the labels **frame.origin.y** to vertically center my label where it needs to be

```
float topPadding = [label.font ascender] - [label.font capHeight];
float bottomPadding = [label.font lineHeight] - [label.font ascender];
```

Comment: Is it possible that the font i am using "gotham" includes this padding and I would need to edit the font?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom UIFont baseline shifted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015317/custom-uifont-baseline-shifted)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Font is the only possible cause of this padding, but if you only need one-line labels, don't waste your time editing the font, just reduce the label's height by those few pixels after setting a proper frame by doing something like this:

```
label.frame = CGRectInset(label.frame, 0, bottomPadding);
```

Also, instead of:

```
CGRect frameLabel = label.frame;
CGSize sizeLabel = [label.text sizeWithFont:label.font];
frameLabel.size.width = sizeLabel.width;
frameLabel.size.height = sizeLabel.height;
```

You can just call:

```
[label sizeToFit];
```

Comment: You confirmed my suspicion. Out of curiosity do you have any idea what property of the font is causing this extra padding at the bottom?

Comment: Just confirmed 100% that it is the actual font that is causing the problem like you said.  I downloaded FontForge and changed every single setting of gotham.ttf to match what Helvetica.ttf has and i was able to get it to remove the extra padding.

Comment: Hi AlBeebe. I'm having the same issue and trying to change some font properties using FontForge. Could you explain me what values did you change? Thanks a lot!

Comment: LocoMike, late reply (9 months later) I'm not sure exactly what setting I changed. Like I said I changed all the properties to match Helvetica and it worked.

Comment: Proposed solution won't help as letters like "y" will be cut in this case. I don't think we can fix it completely just by adjusting frame. I test on Lato font.