# How to adjust the baseline shift for a UiLabel?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uilabel

My app is using custom font to display an information for the whole app.

But there is some problems with their base line like in the image below:

[image]

I need to fix "X 4" to be centered in vertical red box.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Set attributed string with adjusted baseline offset like so in Swift:

```
let sttrStr = NSAttributedString.init(string: "your text",
                                      attributes:[NSAttributedStringKey.baselineOffset: -10])
textLabel.attributedText = attrStr
```

or like so in ObjC:

```
NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"your string"
                              attributes:@{ NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName : @-10 }];
textLabel.attributedText = attrStr;
```

Per SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015317/custom-uifont-baseline-shifted)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `UILabel` and set its size same as the red box. And then set it's text alignment as center:

```
youLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
```

Another not so good option is to make a `UIButton` of same size as red box and set its `UserInteractionEnabled` to `No`. This way your text will be positioned in the center horizontally and vertically. You can also set it's `setContentVerticalAlignment` property

Comment: This is only work for horizontal align  but not in vertical.

Comment: Check the answer again. Edited it